# Prevent enrich from changing parent exchange properties

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have defined following routes:

```
<route id="operation-456">
    <from uri="direct:operation-456" />
    <setProperty propertyName="operationid">
        <constant>456</constant>
    </setProperty>
    <!-- read file -->
</route>

<route id="operation-123">
    <from uri="direct:operation-123" />
    <setProperty propertyName="operationid">
        <constant>123</constant>
    </setProperty>
    <enrich strategyRef="aggregators.MergeListAggregator" shareUnitOfWork="true">
        <constant>direct:operation-456</constant>
    </enrich>
    <to uri="bean:UpdateStocksProcessor" />
</route>
```

When I try to access property `operationId`, I get 456 instead of original operation value 123.

I suspected that enrich only enriches body, but not headers and properties. Is there a way to skip changes to exchange properties or to somehow isolate values?

Edit: MergeListAggregator

```
public class MergeListAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> main = (List<Map<String, Object>>) original.getIn().getBody();
        if(main == null) {
            main = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        List<Map<String, Object>> additional = (List<Map<String, Object>>) resource.getIn().getBody();
        if(additional == null) {
            additional = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        main.addAll(additional);

        original.getOut().setBody(main);

        return original;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you have full control of how to enrich in the `AggregationStrategy` where you can do whatever you want/keep in the `Exchange` instance you return which is the result.

So look at how you have implemented the `aggregators.MergeListAggregator`

Comment: I have updated my question and added MergeListAggregator. I can't see how I'm overwriting exchange properties.